# Related to neo4j and csv files

Tags: csv, file, neo4j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F751s.png)I'm new to neo4j and cypher. I want to create node for multiple sub nodes. I have patient file and I have one allergy file so first I want to create node allergies and then I want to add sub nodes to this node. Then I want to add that allergies node to patient. such as patient-[:has allergies]-allergies<-latex allergy allergies another node for another allergy connected to allergies.
how can I do that in neo4j?
allergy.csv file contains

```
START       Patent id                           DESCRIPTION 
01/05/1982 1d604da9-9a81-4ba9-80c2-de3375d59b40 Latex allergy 
10/25/1982 034e9e3b-2def-4559-bb2a-7850888ae060 Shellfish allergy
```

patient.csv contains

```
Id                                   BIRTHDATE   First Name      ADDRESS 
1d604da9-9a81-4ba9-80c2-de3375d59b40 5/25/1989    Josef       427 Balistreri 
034e9e3b-2def-4559-bb2a-7850888ae060 11/14/1983   milo217    422 Farrell      

CITY         STATE        COUNTY 
Chicopee Massachusetts Hampden County 
Chicopee Massachusetts Hampden County 

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///patients.csv" as row
MERGE (p:patient {name:row.FIRST, id:row.Id, birhdate:row.BIRTHDATE})
MERGE (ad: address {address : row. ADDRESS, state:row.STATE, country:row.COUNTY})
CREATE (p)-[:belongs to]->(ad);

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///allergies.csv" as row
CREATE (a: allergy{name: row. DESCRIPTION, id:row.PATIENT});
MATCH (p:patient), (a: allergy)
WHERE p.id = a.id
MERGE (p)-[:has_allergy] -> (a);
```

Comment: assuming you have a neo4j database to work on, follow this guide on uploading data into neo4j. https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/.  goodluck!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I already gone through this guide. I can load files but I want to create node for that file

Comment: if that is the case, can you post the script that you write to create the nodes? is there an error? if yes, pls post it too. can you share your data model and sample files as well?

Comment: yes I can  where allergy.csv  file contains                                                                                                    
   START                   PATIENT Id                                             DESCRIPTION
01/05/1982  1d604da9-9a81-4ba9-80c2-de3375d59b40   Latex allergy
10/25/1982  034e9e3b-2def-4559-bb2a-7850888ae060   Shellfish allergy

Comment: you created allergy nodes with an attribute, DESCRIPTION.why do you  need another node for that? What is the problem if you query your new databaae?

Comment: I have upload image check it I want such a graph.

Comment: you can remove the node allergy and you dont need it. Is this a school project?

Comment: it is a college minor project

Comment: ya but my teacher want such a graph I want to create such graph that is not created graph

Comment: Okey, I understand your situation; I will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long conversation, I cannot leave this thread without an answer.

```
allery.csv:
START,Patient_id,DESCRIPTION
01/05/1982,1d604da9-9a81-4ba9-80c2-de3375d59b40,Latex allergy
10/25/1982,034e9e3b-2def-4559-bb2a-7850888ae060,Shellfish allergy
10/25/1982,034e9e3b-2def-4559-bb2a-7850888ae060,Pollen allergy


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///allergy.csv" as row
CREATE (a: allergy {name: row.DESCRIPTION, id:row.Patient_id}) 
WITH row, a
MERGE (p:patient {id: row.Patient_id})
WITH p, a
MERGE (p)- [:has_alleries] -> (al:allergy) 
WITH al, a
MERGE (al) <- [:allergy] - (a);
```

COMMENTS to your teacher:

1. the allergy node between allergy and patient is not needed. You can go from allergy to patient directly.
2. the relationship type "allergy" is the same with a node "allergy". You can use a different label say, latex allergy - :of_type  -> allergy.
3. allergy node id is the same with same with patient id. It is not appropriate.

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! It really worked for me and yes I will inform this comments to my teachers.

Comment: More power to you on your learning graphDB.  Doesn't have to be neo4j. :D

Comment: hey am getting one more problem with the same that is I have latex allergy 2 times for the same patient so 2 nodes are created can I create one node for multiple same cells data